# "Aw snap!" message on uploading a large sized directory in chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I am trying to upload a folder present on my local directory to my server on S3 using an API call.
This works fine for small folders(number of files: 100, size: 51mb), however, for large folders(number of files: 868, size: 180mb), the tab crashes after a few seconds giving the message **" Aw snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage."**.

Uploading is done by first selecting the folder on local, which gives me paths of all the files in it and then converting it into a tree structure to send in the body of an API. The folder structure I send at backend has a tree-like structure. The function used is given below:

```
// files are the paths of the files present in the folder
this.readFolder = function(files) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var tree = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      var loadCount = 0;
      var reader = new FileReader();

      if (file.type && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      } else {
        reader.readAsText(file);
      }

      (function(file, reader) {
        reader.onload = function() {
          var path = file.webkitRelativePath.split('/');
          var folder = tree;
          for (var i in path) {
            if (i == path.length - 1) {
              folder[path[i]] = reader.result;
            } else {
              folder[path[i]] = folder[path[i]] || {};
            }
            folder = folder[path[i]];
          }
          loadCount++;
          if (loadCount == files.length) {
            resolve(tree);
          }
        };
      })(file, reader);
    }
  });
};
```

The tree structure returned by the function is then sent in the body of an API.

```
$http.post("/api/upload", {
  data: tree
}).then(function(res) {
  if (res.data.error) {
    toaster.pop('error', '', res.data.reason);
  } else {
    toaster.pop('success', '', 'Uploaded successfully.');
  }
}, function(rej) {
  var error = (rej.data) ? rej.data.msg : "Some error occured.";
  toaster.pop('error', '', error);
});
```

After some digging, I have found out that this might be caused because the body part of the API is converted to a string and sending large strings might create memory issues in chrome. Can somebody tell me exactly why this is not working and how to make it work?

PS: I couldn't find an error logged on the server or developer console. Also after the tab crashes, developer tools gets disconnected.

Also, this is working on Mozilla Firefox.